# Ringing/Oscillation in the reconstructed Periodogram

Tags: power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, autoregressive-model, periodogram

I have an original periodogram that I need to model with autoregressive process. However the model isn't right as it is not fitted well to the original periodogram.

I am suspecting I am doing something wrong when taking the IFFT.

- Normalize the original periodogram $I(f)$ so that the (sum of the integral
  is 1 on the normalized frequency)
- Create a $2N-1\times1$ two sided periodogram from $N$ samples of the normalized periodogram
- Take the $\sqrt{I(f)}$ of the signal from the last step
- Generate random phase values from [0,2pi] and multiply
  the signal point with the phasors from the phase
- Perform IFFT (Scipy IFFT,  0 frequency content - positive side content - negative side    content )
- Autocorrelate the generated IFFT signal
- Use Autocorrelation method to solve for the AR parameters
- Finally fit the AR model and generate Periodogram

\begin{equation}
 I(f)= \frac{1}{|\hat{A}(f)|^2} = \frac{1}{|a[0] + a[1]e^{-j2\pi f_1} + a[2]e^{-j2\pi f_2} +....+  a[p]e^{-j2\pi f_p}|^2} 
\end{equation}

where $p$ is the AR model order

[image]

Sorry, I can't show the whole plot for a reason. I am only showing the end of positive side spectrum

what am I doing wrong ?